# Custom ID generator in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, identity

HI all,

How to do functionality of generator class="assigned" as well as generator class="native" together.

in my case some situation i will have ID another case i dont know the ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Acurus.Capella.Core.DomainObjects" assembly="User">
  <class name="UserLookup, Core" table="User_lookup" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="User_ID">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Acurus.Capella.Core.DomainObjects" assembly="User">
  <class name="UserLookup, Core" table="User_lookup" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="User_ID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own implementation of `IIdentifierGenerator` using code from both `NHibernate.Id.Assigned` and whatever concrete implementation of "native" corresponds to your DB, like `NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator`.

However, as Ids *should* be meaningless, I don't know why you would "have ID" before persisting an entity.

Comment: How to Create Custom IidentifierGenerator Class for Both Assigned and native Generator